# How to add my condition on concatenated query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, dynamic-sql

I want to add my dynamic condition on my `SQL Server` query but found that I should use concatenated query.

I'm new on concatenated query. Here's below query I tried but having error incorrect systax.

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(500) = ' and ID IN (1,2)';
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);


SET @sql = '
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500)
);

DELETE FROM @table
INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    Amount,
    Name
)
VALUES
(1, 200, ''ab''),
(2, 300, ''ab''),
(3, -150, ''ac''),
(4, 200, ''ab'');

select SUM(Amount)
from @table
where name = ''ab'' ''' + @value + ''';';
EXEC (@sql);
```

What is the proper way adding condition query variable on my concatenated query.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: This looks like an injection problem, if ever I saw one.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ' and ID IN (1,2)'.

Comment: STOP blindly applying patterns. If you declare a table variable, there is absolutely no need to delete rows from that table variable immediately after the declaration. It cannot possibly have any rows at that point. In fact, why do you need a table variable at all? Just use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your code:

- missing semi-column at the end of the `delete` statement
- extract quote after the `where name = ''ab''` and at the end of the code

This should work:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(500) = ' and ID IN (1,2)';
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500)
);

DELETE FROM @table;
INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    Amount,
    Name
)
VALUES
(1, 200, ''ab''),
(2, 300, ''ab''),
(3, -150, ''ac''),
(4, 200, ''ab'');

select SUM(Amount)
from @table
where name = ''ab'' ' + @value + ';';
EXEC(@sql);
```

Notes:

- this is called *dynamic SQL* rather than *concatenated query*
- a simple way to debug such code is to replace the `EXEC(@sql)` command with `SELECT @sql`, which lets you see the SQL generated by your code; in [this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=02aab96b6b958eb983534645d93ea0cf), you can see the result:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500)
);

DELETE FROM @table;
INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    Amount,
    Name
)
VALUES
(1, 200, 'ab'),
(2, 300, 'ab'),
(3, -150, 'ac'),
(4, 200, 'ab');

select SUM(Amount)
from @table
where name = 'ab'  and ID IN (1,2);
```

Comment: Have you checked this code is not working and giving error - Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ';'.

Comment: In below query last line contains an extra single quote, please review.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove extra quotes :

```
where name = ''ab'' ' + @value + ';';
```

Comment: It works, the problem is I have set my variable value as String. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi use below modify query

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(500) = ' and ID IN (1,2)';
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);


SET @sql = '
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    Name VARCHAR(500)
);

DELETE FROM @table
INSERT INTO @table
(
    ID,
    Amount,
    Name
)
VALUES
(1, 200, ''ab''),
(2, 300, ''ab''),
(3, -150, ''ac''),
(4, 200, ''ab'');

select SUM(Amount)
from @table
where name = ''ab''' + @value+';'
EXEC (@sql);
```

Query Output: 500